# New users vs returning users never decrease

Tags: google-analytics

You would expect that the number of '**new users**' would decrease over time, and the number of '**returning users**' would accumulate. This should be the case because in our marketing we only target 'known' users. However, even when measured over a longer period of time (2 years) the number of new visitors never decreases, why is that?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why the number of 'new users' would decrease? What segment do you analyze?